# Stellaris LM3S8962 Port E Interrupt

Tags: interrupt, stellaris

I am new to Stellaris LM3S8962. I want to inquire about how to write 4 separate ISRs to handle interrupts originated from 4 buttons Up, Down, Left, Right. I have tried but my code always fell into FaultISR.
Thanks!

Comment: You have to show your code, otherwise it's really hard to find a bug in it. Also check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. **Both** links I have sent you. You'll find out what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5j5il9kt324o943/Lab%202.rar?dl=0

The link above is my project.
It works fine, but when I add the following statements to the Startup task it would fall into FaultISR

```
// Configure the UART 
SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_UART0);
SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOA);
// Enable processor interrupts.
IntMasterEnable();
// Set GPIO A0 and A1 as UART pins.
GPIOPinTypeUART(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1);
// Configure the UART for 9600, 8-N-1 operation.
UARTConfigSetExpClk(UART0_BASE, SysCtlClockGet(), 9600,
                        (UART_CONFIG_WLEN_8 | UART_CONFIG_STOP_ONE |
                         UART_CONFIG_PAR_NONE));
// Enable the UART interrupt.
IntEnable(INT_UART0);
UARTIntEnable(UART0_BASE, UART_INT_RX | UART_INT_RT);
```